# group with lookup's foreign field in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, orm, nosql-aggregation

I have two different models:

- Promotions
- Tags

Each promotion has a field with a reference to a tag ID. That was referenced on my schema and works fine:

```
const PromotionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    tags: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tag' }
}, { collection: 'promotions' });
```

My question is how to create a custom response that group all the promotions by tag? Something like this:

```
{ 
   "tag": {
     "_id": "999",
     "value": "Lorem Ipsum"
   },
   "promotions": [{
      "_id": "0001",
      "value": "Value of promotion Nº1"
   },
   {
      "_id": "0002",
      "value": "Value of promotion Nº2"
   },
    ... And the others that have the same Tag ID assigned
   ]}
}
```

Right now, I'm getting all the promotions and filtering using Vanilla Javascript. I need to know how to improve this using Mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregate function to achieve the result...

If you have mongodb version **3.6**

```
db.promotion.aggregate([
  // stage 1
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Promotions.collection.name,
    "let": { "tags": "$tags" },
    "pipeline": [
       { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$tags" ] } } }
     ],
     "as": "tags"
  }},
  // stage 2
  { "$addFields": { 
    "tags": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$tags", 0 ] }
  }},
  // stage 3
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$tags._id",
    "promotions": {
        "$push": {
            "fieldName1": "$fieldName1",
            "fieldName2": "$fieldName2",
        }
    }
  }}
 ])
```

If you have mongodb version prior to **3.6**

```
db.promotion.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Promotions.collection.name,
    "localField": "tags",
    "foreignField": "_id"
     "as": "tags"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "tags" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$tags._id",
    "promotions": {
        "$push": {
            "fieldName1": "$fieldName1",
            "fieldName2": "$fieldName2",
        }
    }
  }}
 ])
```

Both will give similar output

```
{ 
   "tag": {
     "_id": "999",
     "value": "Lorem Ipsum"
   },
   "promotions": [{
      "_id": "0001",
      "value": "Value of promotion Nº1"
   },
   {
      "_id": "0002",
      "value": "Value of promotion Nº2"
   }
   ]}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but after of apply your code, I'm getting ```error: MongoError: arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { tags: "$tags" } is type 3```

Comment: @JonathanBrizio Actually you have older mongodb version... Please check the updated answer...